# How to get id for group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have sql script for grouping values

```
select count(*), equity_name, date, field
from balance
group by equity_name, date, field
having count(*)>1
```

How can i get ids for each group? In future i need to insert dublicates values to another table.

My current result:

[image: cur_res]

Result what i need:

[image: result]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What do *you* mean by "ids for each group"?

Comment: `array_agg(id)`?

Comment: i updated the post

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign a sequential number to the groups, you can use:

```
select count(*), equity_name, date, field,
       row_number() over (order by equity_name, date, field) as id
from balance
group by equity_name, date, field
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you want a stable "name" for the group that doesn't depend on the data in the table, you can just concatenate the fields together:

```
select count(*), equity_name, date, field,
       concat_ws(':', equity_name, date, field) as id
from balance
group by equity_name, date, field
having count(*) > 1;
```

However, if you really care about persisting the group over time, I would suggest that you save the results into a table with an auto-generated `identity` column.

Comment: @DjFenomen . . . Why not just use the integer returned by `row_number()`?

Comment: i need to know uuid for every dublicate row

Comment: @DjFenomen . . . There are no duplicate rows in a `group by` query.

Comment: in my case on every date there is only one row for equity_name and field. if count more than 1, it's dublicate for me